# How to interpolate data and create a Density Plot?

Tags: plotting

I have data of the form:

```
image := {{0.1,0.5,0.8}, {0.8,0.9,0.001}...}
```

where the entries correspond to the following: `{x-coordinate, y-coordinate, brightness}` and the data does not correspond to every grid point.  (Note the brightness is usually between 0 and 1.)

I wish to create a density graph in *Mathematica* based on the data to give the a graph similar to the following:

[image: Density Graph]

White represents 1's and blacks represents 0's.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to convert your data to the below form:

```
myData = {{#[[1]], #[[2]]}, #[[3]]} & /@ rawData;
```

Then:

```
myData = {{{1, 1}, 1}, {{1, 2}, 2}, {{1, 2.5}, 3}, {{1, 4}, 
   4}, {{2, 1}, 2}, {{2, 2}, 2}, {{2, 3}, 6}, {{2, 3.2}, 4}, {{3, 1}, 
   3}, {{3, 2}, 6}, {{3, 3}, 3}, {{3, 4.2}, 12}, {{4, 1.6}, 
   4}, {{4, 2}, 4}, {{4, 3}, 12}, {{4, 4}, 4}};

f = Interpolation[myData, InterpolationOrder -> All]

DensityPlot[f[x, y], {x, 1, 4}, {y, 1, 4}]
```

Comment: I want it to interpolate the data, as not all the squares are covered

Answer (score 1):

```
ListDensityPlot[
 Catenate@Table[{x, y, RandomReal[]}, {x, 1, 20}, {y, 1, 20}],
 PlotTheme -> "Monochrome"]
```

[image]